# Input type file on select option

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, input, laravel-blade

Is there a way for instance with bootstrap, to put an

```
input type="file"
```

for each `option` in a `select` field?

So that I can pick a file for each option?

```
<fieldset class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" id="language_selection" name="language_selection[]" multiple>
        @foreach($languages as $languageKey => $languageValue)
            <option value="<?php echo $languageValue->short_name; ?>"><?php echo $languageValue->name; ?></option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</fieldset>
```

I want to add an input file for each option the user selects, how can I accomplish this?

**Edit**

These are the option values:

```
'de'
'pt'
'en'
'es'
'ru'
'nl'
'fr'
'bo'
'da'
'et'
'fi'
'sv'
'ge'
'el'
'is'
'it'
'hr'
'lv'
'lt'
'mk'
'ro'
'me'
'nw'
'pl'
'se'
'sk'
'sl'
'cs'
'tr'
'uk'
'hu'
'bg'
'ga'
'mt'
```

Comment: @foreach is not Bootstrap, its Blade - you may wish to edit accordingly and adjust your tags.

Comment: the @foreach is not important now I think, just wanted to show that I am runnning through on foreach

Comment: Ok, you are generating the options of the select with php, right, and now, with JavaScript you want to create an input file for each selected value on the select, right?

Comment: @Hackerman yes something like that

Comment: Can you put the html generated for the select with the all the options?...and, can I use Jquery or it needs to be done in plain JS?

Comment: you can use jquery of course:) ill post the options quick 1min

Comment: @Hackerman I added the options to my question ill have to go in 5-10 minutes so ill give you a reply tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question, I was able to achieve the following with **Jquery**:

> Html

```
<fieldset class="form-group">
<select class="form-control" id="language_selection" name="language_selection[]" multiple>
    <option value="de">Deutschland</option>
    <option value="pt">Portugal</option>
    <option value="en">England</option>
    <option value="es">Espana</option>
</select>
</fieldset>
<div id="divFileInput"></div>
```

> Jquery

```
$('#language_selection').change(function(){
    var selections = $("#language_selection :selected");
    var html = '';
    $.each(selections,function(i,item){
        html += $(item).text()+':<input type="file" id="'+$(item).val()+'" /><br>';
    })
    $('#divFileInput').html(html);
})
```

#### Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/f4ze70yq/